# aws :: cloudformation :: possibilities to get current userID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My requirement is to automatically get the current userID and use it as part of cloudfromation stack.
Any valuable inputs will be appreciable.
Thanks

Tried CloudFormation with Lambda but it is returning Lambda Role information.

Comment: You would need to go to CloudTrail to retrieve this information. But IMO that's a bad solution. If you need to associate a stack's resources with a user, then force them to enter a parameter value when creating the stack.

Comment: Currently users adding their details manually, but sometimes they are entering wrong details. even to evaluate that need to get user info dynamically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.